# How to use the matrix strategy to generate ad-hoc and app store builds for ios on Azure Pipelines (YAML)?

Tags: ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to generate the ad-hoc and app-store builds for my iOS app from Azure Pipelines. There's this task that allows us to get the Provisioning Profile from Secure Files:

```yaml
# Install Apple Provisioning Profile
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: Install Apple provisioning profile
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: $(appleProvProfileId)
```

Now I have different Provisioning Profiles for the different builds:

- ProvProfileAdHoc with Secure Files ID - 123456
- ProvProfileAppStore with Secure Files ID - 098765

Here's what I have tried:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: build_ios
    displayName: Build iOS
    strategy:
      matrix:
        adhoc:
          appleProvProfileId: 123456
        appstore:
          appleProvProfileId: 098765
    steps:
      # Install Apple Provisioning Profile
      - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        displayName: Install Apple provisioning profile
        inputs:
          provProfileSecureFile: $(appleProvProfileId)
```

However, when I run this, there's an error saying that the pipeline cannot find the variable.

```
Starting: Install Apple provisioning profile
==============================================================================
Task         : Install Apple provisioning profile
Description  : Install an Apple provisioning profile required to build on a macOS agent machine
Version      : 1.200.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile
==============================================================================
##[error]Error: Input required: provProfileSecureFile.           <-------- ERROR HERE!
Finishing: Install Apple provisioning profile
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> How to use the matrix strategy to generate ad-hoc and app store builds for ios on Azure Pipelines (YAML)?

This should be the limit of the task itself.

When you check it with Classic pipeline, we couold find that the option Provisioning profile is a **drop-down menu** and does not accept variables：

[image]

That is reason why we could not use the variable for `$(appleProvProfileId)`.

I use `echo` syntax to test your YAML and it works fine：

[image]